# Angular 7 file upload issue with php yii2

Tags: php, angular, yii2

Angular 7 Code
component html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" (change)="onUpload($event.target.files)">
</form>
```

component ts:

```
onUpload(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    //console.log(this.fileToUpload);
    this.accountService.upload(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(data => {
        // do something, if upload success
        console.log(data);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

### service code

```
upload(fileToUpload: File): Observable < boolean > {

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload);
    return this.http.post('api/user/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }),
        catchError(this.gs.handleHttpError)
    );
}
```

Then php, we get file content,  `$_FILE` is empty 
we get

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryw65P85l6cgPLtiXG
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "file"; filename="88283fdfe821ebd5f3e86f7300237f03.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

such data at php

Comment: IMK, in PHP `$_FILES` is a superglobal, not `$_FILE`

Comment: Yes $_FILES superglobal